# datatable is displaying old value when i click next or previous button.

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

im using jquery datatable for displaying data based on user search using ajax. the datatable is not refreshing. it is displaying first time loaded value when i click next or previous button.

```
function searchCustomer() {

 var frm = $("#customerDetailSearchForm").serializeObject();
 $("#tbl_contact_search_result").hide();

 $.ajax({ 
 type: 'POST', 
 url: restContextPath + '/IONSWeb/rest/order/searchContact', 
 data: JSON.stringify(frm),
 dataType: 'json',
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 success: function(data, status, xhr) {             
         $("#tbl_contact_search_result tbody").empty();
     $.each(data.body, function(i, item) {                 
         var checkBox = item.actionString;
         var dataTableBodyHTML = '<tr><td>'+ checkBox + '</td><td>'+ item.name + '</td><td>'+ item.street +'</td><td>' + item.city + '</td><td>'+ item.state + '</td><td>' + item.phone +'</td></tr>';

         $("#tbl_contact_search_result tbody").append(dataTableBodyHTML);            
         $("#tbl_contact_search_result").show();
     });        
         var dataTable = $('#tbl_contact_search_result').DataTable();

        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {               
              $('.ErrorMsg').html('<h5>An error has occurred</h5>');
           }
        });
  }
```

Comment: Does the post return give you the corrrect data? Maybe it's cached? Or is the data correct and is the table just not updating?

Comment: @Shilly, yes im getting correct data in response and datatable is displaying that data in first 10 records. if i navigate to second page using next button or clicking pagination it is displaying old data. and  if i click on sorting also it is displaying old data. the new is data is immediately disappearing.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a conflict between this function and another function that sets the contents of the data table. Is this the only function that appends data to the table body?

Comment: yes, this is the only function that appends data to the table body.

Comment: Hmm, have a look at the manuals for the datatable library then, you might have to use other code or something to get the navigate/sort things to work if you didn't write those yourself. No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the ajax caching feature. [The default value is true](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). So, you have to set it as false. (cache: false)

```
function searchCustomer() {

 var frm = $("#customerDetailSearchForm").serializeObject();
 $("#tbl_contact_search_result").hide();

 $.ajax({ 
 type: 'POST', 
 url: restContextPath + '/IONSWeb/rest/order/searchContact', 
 data: JSON.stringify(frm),
 dataType: 'json',
 cache: false,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 success: function(data, status, xhr) {             
         $("#tbl_contact_search_result tbody").empty();
     $.each(data.body, function(i, item) {                 
         var checkBox = item.actionString;
         var dataTableBodyHTML = '<tr><td>'+ checkBox + '</td><td>'+ item.name + '</td><td>'+ item.street +'</td><td>' + item.city + '</td><td>'+ item.state + '</td><td>' + item.phone +'</td></tr>';

         $("#tbl_contact_search_result tbody").append(dataTableBodyHTML);            
         $("#tbl_contact_search_result").show();
     });        
         var dataTable = $('#tbl_contact_search_result').DataTable();

        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {               
              $('.ErrorMsg').html('<h5>An error has occurred</h5>');
           }
        });
  }
```

Comment: i have added  cache: false, even it is showing old data when i click on pagination button. first page in data-table showing new values when i click on pagination button only it is showing old value. so, problem is in ajax, i think problem is in data-table only

Comment: Maybe you are using some caching feature in your system